# why restricted view simply block the user?

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-server, permissions, sharepoint-permissions

I tried to use restricted view as a permission level for a group. But the group was unable to access the site and kept asking for access. So I change the permission level to Read but had restricted view for the libraries. In this case, the visitor can access the site but is blocked at the library again.

Can someone explain the restricted view permissions because it is not doing what it is supposed to based on descriptor?

Comment: Which SharePoint version you are using? Also check this [article](https://natechamberlain.com/2020/08/10/read-vs-restricted-read-vs-view-only-permission-in-sharepoint/) which might help you to understand the permissions.

Answer (score 0):

You have to distinguish Restricted view from Restricted read permission level. If Restricted view is given to a user/group in site-level, it is no use. The user will still be unable to access anywhere in that site. Restricted view should be given as unique permission in a list or a library for the user can only view items in a list or library.
I am curious that as per my test, if I give read permission level to a user but give restricted view for the libraries, the user can access those libraries in my end.

Comment: Thank you for the response. Unfortunately, when I gave read permission to a group (site-level sitting) but limited their access to 'restricted view' to the various libraries (in library setting), the users were not able to access the materials in the libraries...any clue?